# How do I mock `csv.DictWriter.writeheader()`, which is called from within my custom function?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I have a custom function defined in

**custom_file.py**

```py
import csv

def write_dict_to_csv(columns=None, file_name=None, data=None):
    try:
        with open(file_name, "w") as f:
            writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=columns)
            writer.writeheader()
```

in **test_file.py** I want to return a fixed value when `writer.writeheader()` is called.

```py
from custom_file import write_dict_to_csv

class TestMyFunctions(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch('custom_file.csv.DictWriter.writeheader')
    def test_write_dict_to_csv(self, mock_writeheader):
        custom_file.write_dict_to_csv(file_name='fileName')
        self.assertTrue(mock_writeheader.called)
```

But this returns `TypeError: stat: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer, not NoneType`

How do I mock `csv.DictWriter.writeheader()` when it's being imported from an external library into a `custom_file`, which I'm then testing from a separate `test_file`?

I figured this would be close to correct since we're meant to patch where a thing is looked up, not where it is defined.

Comment: Better idea: have `write_dict_to_csv` take a file-like object, not a file name. Then you can pass a `StringIO` value as that object; no mocking necessary.

Comment: Your function is still trying to call `open(None, "w")` before it even tries to use the mocked value.

Comment: Thanks @chepner. I omitted the file name when simplifying the code for clarity. Put it back now. I read about `StringIO`. I have several other situations where external library methods are called from within custom functions and If I learn how to do this simple case I think It'll help with those.

Comment: Another problem is that `DictWriter.writeheader` isn't what's being called; it's the method return by its `__get__` method (which is called by `writer.writeheader`). In any case, what you want to avoid in a unit test is file I/O in the first place, which would mean mocking `open`, not any part of `DictWriter`.

Comment: Ah, ok! Yes, the error I was seeing was not due to the patching exactly but to the fact that I'm not mocking the open and file. That puts me on a correct path. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The code you have provided does not run "as is" because of some missing imports, but after fixing the problems everything seems working (the test passes).
Here is the code I ran. I hope it helps.

custom_file.py

```
import csv


def write_dict_to_csv(columns=None, file_name=None, data=None):
    with open(file_name, "w") as f:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=columns)
        writer.writeheader()
```

test_file.py

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch

import custom_file


class TestMyFunctions(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch('custom_file.csv.DictWriter.writeheader')
    def test_write_dict_to_csv(self, mock_writeheader):
        print("Hello")
        custom_file.write_dict_to_csv(file_name='fileName')
        self.assertTrue(mock_writeheader.called)
```

Comment: I omitted the unittest imports in the post but had them in the real code. I guess one mis-step was `from custom_file import ...` vs `import custom_file`? The latter allows for the path in the patch statement? Thanks Pavel